# Start-AzAutomationRunbook keeps failing with 'Runbook mandatory parameter not specified. Parameter name ResourceGroupName.'

Tags: azure, powershell

I am trying to start an automation runbook with powershell but the command keeps failing with the following error...

```
Start-AzAutomationRunbook : Runbook mandatory parameter not specified. Parameter name ResourceGroupName.
```

This is the command I am running...

```
Start-AzAutomationRunbook -AutomationAccountName "existingAccountName" -Name "existingRB" -ResourceGroupName "existingRG" -MaxWaitSeconds 2000 -Wait
```

I've confirmed the automation account exists, the resource group exists, the runbook exists. I've successfully started the runbook in the console without error.

I would like the runbook to start when the Start-AzAutomationRunbook is run in powershell.

Comment: you'd need to pass in the parameter to the runbook? you are only specifying which runbook to start, not passing the parameter to the runbook?

Comment: Yep, that was it. I didn't even realize the runbook had required parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you job script requires a `resourcegroupname` parameter to run. The resource group you specify in line below is the resource group for account where the run book is.

`Start-AzAutomationRunbook -AutomationAccountName "existingAccountName" -Name "existingRB" -ResourceGroupName "existingRG" -MaxWaitSeconds 2000 -Wait`

To apply a resource group or parameter to an actual job you will have to pass parameters, below should work if all you job needs is ResourceGroupName.

`$AutomationRG = "existingRG"`

`$params = @{"ResourceGroupName"="$AutomationRG"}`

`Start-AzureRmAutomationRunbook -AutomationAccountName "existingAccountName" -Name "existingRB" -ResourceGroupName $AutomationRG -Parameters $params`